# What is the difference between a clinical inventory and personal inventory?

Tags: clinical-psychology

I was looking at different phyc products online and notice that some inventories are called personal inventories and some are called clincal. This made me wonder if this was just the name the publishing company gave them or if these were really two different classes of inventory and also if the latter, what is the difference? The example I came across was the [Minnesota Multi-phasic Personality Inventory (MMPI)](https://psychcentral.com/lib/minnesota-multiphasic-personality-inventory-mmpi/) and the [Millon Adolescent Clinical Inventory (MACI)](https://www.millonpersonality.com/inventories/MACI/#:%7E:text=The%20MACI%20inventory%20Millon%20Adolescent,rate%20scores%2C%20and%20interpretive%20depth.) instrument. Please note that I am asking this about psychological intruments as whole subject rather than these specific intruments.